# How to import existing notes from iPhone to Evernote?

Tags: evernote, migrate-data, apple-notes

I have over 450 existing notes on my iPhone 4 which I sync with Outlook on a PC. I would like to import all these notes into Evernote which has far greater functionality as a notes application [bolding, bullet points etc].

How to achieve this other than one-by-one cut and paste?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be a native solution, but you can do it via Outlook (on Windows at list). It's a rather lengthily road and it involves a VBA script, but it's doable. [This](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/import-iphone-notes-to-evernote-via.html) blog post explains the process in detail.

> **Import iPhone Notes to Evernote via Outlook**
>
> Here's a simple way to import your iPhone notes to Evernote. This solution requires Microsoft Outlook, so it will only work on the PC. Note this could just as easily be used for importing Outlook Notes into Evernote without an iPhone... just skip the first step! The main benefit of this method is that it will retain the creation date of all of your notes.

Here is another one that does the same thing (the importing), but you have to sync your iPhone with Outlook first: http://www.fourteenminutes.com/code/outlook2evernote/